# Linear regulators - Stability, Phase/Gain Margin, Ltspice

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, control-system, ldo, linear-regulator

I am trying to understand how the output capacitor and the ESR of the output capacitor has an effet on the stability of a linear regulators. So I decided to measure the phase margin and the gain margin in function of the ESR of the output capacitor and the value of the output capacitor. The others parameters are kept constants. So in the above system, there is oscillation if :

[image]

$$|G(s)H(s)| = 1 $$
$$arg(G(s)H(s)) = 180° $$

Well, my problem is where is G(s) and H(s) in a linear regulator. Here is my simulation, I applied a technique provided by Middlebrock that I completely do not know (I will take a look on it) but analog device recommand to use it (https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-basic-steps-in-generating-a-bode-plot-of-smps.html) :

[image]

So I supposed that in this position :

$$\frac{V_B}{V_A} = G(s)H(s)$$

And I observed the ac simulation for  having the gain margin and the phase margin ...

Here is the result for a output capacitor of 5µF and an ESR equal to 100mOhm

[image]

Here is the result for a output capacitor of 100µF and an ESR equal to 100mOhm

[image]

If someone can tell me how to do to observe the influence of the output capacitor, it would be nice :D I will be happy to hear any recommandations. I am actually reading a book on this subject.

Thank you and have a nice day !

Comment: Extend the plot for higher frequencies until it does pass unity.

Comment: Then enhance the image contrast so I can see it outside

Comment: ESR has no memory of pumped current.. Imagine driving a car with steering on 10 deg of slack that causes no control. It behaves like no gain , eyes giving negative feedback. You dither all over the middle of the lane or oscillate with high gain.  Like a really worn out ball joint. Yet if you have none on a CMOS LDO, you cant see any mV ripple until you over correct, then too little ESR is bad, but that is not a 2nd order loop.

Comment: LT1117 is a linear regulator, you can use `.AC` analysis to directly observe the phase. What you need is a switching regulator, try, for example, LT3430 (it's simple and switches at 200 kHz, compared to others). You can modify its test schematic for that. (also, it's Middlebrook).

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Comment: Thank you for your help ! @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I do not understand all what you say ... Why ESR give me no control over a certain interval of command ?

Comment: Did you mean that if I am not in a 2nd order loop, I can't have an open loop phase equal to -180° ?